# JQuery fixed header that hides on scroll down and shows on scroll up

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am currently working on a site product where I have to create a site-header that is always fixed on top of the viewport but when I scroll down it hides, and again when I scroll up, it becomes visible again. Actually, I made it happen somehow but I think the JQuery I used can be simpler and currently has some unnecessary variations in it. I used the JQuery from a reference available on internet.

Here is my code.

HTML

```html
<header class="site-header">
    <div class="inner">
    </div>
</header>
```

CSS

```css
.site-header {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
z-index: 1;
width: 100%;
height: 60px;
background: #fff;
transition: transform .25s;}

.hidden {transform:translateY(-100%)}
```

JQuery

```js
jQuery( function( $ ) {
    var didScroll;
    var lastScrollTop = 0;
    var delta = 5;
    var navbarHeight = $('.site-header').outerHeight();

    $(window).scroll(function(event){
        didScroll = true;
    });

setInterval(function() {
    if (didScroll) {
    hasScrolled();
    didScroll = false;
    }
}, 250);

function hasScrolled() {
var st = $(this).scrollTop();

// Make scroll more than delta
if(Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta)
    return;

// If scrolled down and past the site-header, add class .hidden.
if (st > lastScrollTop && st > navbarHeight){
    // Scroll Down
    $('.site-header').addClass('hidden');
} else {
    // Scroll Up
    if(st + $(window).height() < $(document).height()) {
        $('.site-header').removeClass('hidden');
    }
}

lastScrollTop = st;
}
} );
```

Now, all these things together are functional and I have a header that is fixed; when I scroll down, it disappears and when I scroll back up, it becomes visible again - as I wanted. But, since I am not very familiar with JQuery, I am not sure whether this JQuery could be simpler.  I think it would be great if I can achieve the same results with a smaller and simpler JQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First** improvement I saw is about that always `true` condition:

```
if (st + $(window).height() < $(document).height())
```

The amount of pixel scrolled + the viewport height simply cannot be greater than the document height. ;)

Knowing this... You end up with a simple `if`/`else` condition to add or remove the `hidden` class. So instead of it, you can use [toggleClass](https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/#toggleClass-className-state) and use the condition result as the second argument.

```
function hasScrolled() {
  var st = $(this).scrollTop();

  // Make scroll more than delta
  if (Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta) return;

  $(".site-header").toggleClass("hidden", st > lastScrollTop && st > navbarHeight);

  lastScrollTop = st;
}
```

**Second** is about the interval... I think it's useless to run the `hasScrolled` function every 250ms when this does the same visual effect:

```
$(window).scroll(hasScrolled);
```

**Last**: do not use `var`!. `let` or `const` are better. [Read here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11444416/2159528)

I left the `delta` in there, but for 5 pixels, I think it's useless too. Maybe there is a use-case for a bigger value...

Here is the improved code that I suggest:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
  let lastScrollTop = 0;
  const delta = 5;
  const navbarHeight = $(".site-header").outerHeight();
  const header = $(".site-header")

  $(window).scroll(hasScrolled);

  function hasScrolled() {
    const st = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta) return;
    header.toggleClass("hidden", st > lastScrollTop && st > navbarHeight);
    lastScrollTop = st;
  }
});
```

---

Without `delta`:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
  let lastScrollTop = 0;
  const navbarHeight = $(".site-header").outerHeight();
  const header = $(".site-header")

  $(window).scroll(hasScrolled);

  function hasScrolled() {
    const st = $(this).scrollTop();
    header.toggleClass("hidden", st > lastScrollTop && st > navbarHeight);
    lastScrollTop = st;
  }
});
```

Comment: Precisely, greatly explained. Thanks! I checked the code as well on the site, it is working absolutely fine. Since you mentioned, delta in the Jquery is also useless, can you please also provide a Jquery with delta removed? I would check it on the site and see if has any difference from the result I am expecting with the Jquery.

Comment: Sure, it's done. You only had 2 lines to remove ;)

Comment: Thanks! It works great.

Answer (score 0):

### Jquery?

Jquery is dead, using it only adds bloat to the running code and noise to the source code.

We have a lot to thank JQuery for as it guided the development of modern DOM manipulation. So much so that using jQuery on modern browsers is pointless. Detrimental both  to the page and the developer creating it.

Everyday you spend improving your jQuery skills is a day you lose learning modern DOM manipulation. Stay relevant?

### Vanilla JS and DOM

### [Element.id](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/id)

Give your elements (eg header) a unique id that you use to easily get references without the need to use DOM queries

```
<header class="site-header" id="navbarEl">
    <div class="inner">
    </div>
</header>

<script>
    console.log(navbarEl.offsetHeight); // show navbarEl height
</script>
```

### [`window`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/window)

When using vanilla JS [`window`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/window) is the default `this` (AKA [`globalThis`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/globalThis)) and thus there is no need to reference it.

However you already use this pattern when referencing accessing `window.document`. Best you use the same pattern throughout the code. Using the less noisy default `document`, rather than `window.document`

### Example

There are many more ways vanilla JS can improve your codes performance and decrease source complexity. However the existing answer has been accepted so I will just leave it with an rewrite example.

**Note:** that the example does not need to load and run jQuery and all DOM manipulations now use native methods

**Note:** that the code is started on the [page load event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event) (same as `$.ready`) which was missing from your code. This is important if the page headers' size is dependent on loaded content (eg images)

#### DOM referenced

- `scrollY` AKA [`window.scrollY`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollY)
- `addEventListener` AKA [`window.addEventListener` or `EventTarget.addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)
- [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) provides [`className`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className) (AKA [`HTML class`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/class)) manipulation .
- [`HTMLElement.offsetHeight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetHeight)

```js
addEventListener("load", () => {
    var lastY = scrollY;
    const MAX_SCROLL_DELTA = 5, NAV_HEIGHT = navbarEl.offsetHeight;
    addEventListener("scroll", () => {
       const delta = scrollY - lastY;
       if (Math.abs(delta) > MAX_SCROLL_DELTA) {
           navbarEl.classList.toggle("hiddeNavBar", delta > 0 && scrollY > NAV_HEIGHT);
           lastY = scrollY;
       }
    });
});
```

```css
.site-header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    background: #DDD;
    transition: transform 0.25s;
}

.hiddeNavBar {transform:translateY(-100%)}
.contentSpace { padding: 50px; }
```

```html
<header class="site-header" id="navbarEl">
    <div class="inner"> Header
    </div>
</header>
<div>
<div class="contentSpace">Content</div>
<div class="contentSpace">Content</div>
<div class="contentSpace">Content</div>
<div class="contentSpace">Content</div>
<div class="contentSpace">Content</div>
<div class="contentSpace">Content</div>
<div class="contentSpace">Content</div>
<div class="contentSpace">Content</div>
<div class="contentSpace">Content</div>
<div class="contentSpace">Content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I agree with you when it comes to develop a whole new application... jQuery can now be avoided. Now most devs will have to work on existing code to quickly add or modify a tiny feature. Knowing jQuery, as it was widely used for years and still is used in millions of sites, it is a card in hand. The choice to play it or not is opinion based.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette Page speed is a very important factor in website’s ranking (SEO). It is not an opinion that using jQuery slows the page and puts the site at a disadvantage against not using jQuery.

Comment: Thanks Blindman67. Actually, I haven't much learned about DOM yet. I ain't kind of familiar to it. But, JQuery, it is being used by most websites till date. Also, I have my site integrated to WooCommerce that also has JQuery functionality.

Comment: And, Blindman67, talking about SEO, it is a whole different thing. In my opinion, JQuery doesn't affect SEO rankings that much. Using HTML5 like <header>,<footer>,<nav>,<main>,<article>,<aside> and structuring your site well obviously gives an edge in SERP rankings. Also, talking about site speed, a site first loads basic structure, css. Then the browser loads the scripts. JS is a backend thing and a site first loads the frontend, so I don't think it much affects or slows site loading until it is overused everywhere.